# How to recover lost Xbox savegame for GTA V?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

For some odd reason my latest quicksave was at 32% when it got ovrewritten with one at 28% game progress. I am using Xbox 360 with no internet connection.

Is it possible to recover the previous savegame? I am also wondering if savegames can be transfered to Xbox? That way I could hopefully find a proper savegame online and play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly not.

Even assuming the old save wasn't physically overwritten and is still there, Xbox saves are protected to prevent cheating. Messing around with the save files would be difficult, would violate the TOS, and could result in loss of gamerscore or other unintended consequences.

You're better off just replaying that 4% of the game.

Comment: Unless it was a quicksave, and your Xbox time settings were changed. Then choose load game and the other save may be there. You  may have had your Xbox unplugged. Agreed with Studoku there too.

Comment: Brok3n, that did occur, great idea! Will try out in the evening.

Comment: Well that didn't work but I could skip the missions after failing each of them for a few times on purpose ASAP.